# What is the minimal number of generators for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

With generators for  $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ I mean a set $a_0,...,a_m\in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)(\mathbb{P}^n)$ such that $a_0,...,a_m$ generate $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)_P$ at all points $P$. I want to say that any generating set must have at least $n+1$ elements but I'm not sure how to prove it or if it's even true. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Informally $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ is the set of homogeneous polynomials of degree $1$. Once you figure out how to formalise this the rest shouldn't be too tricky.

Comment: This I understand. What I tried to prove is that if $a_0,...,a_m$ generate $\mathcal{O}(1)$ then they must span the vector space $\mathcal{O}(1)(\mathbb{P}^n)$ which has dimension n+1. Is this the right approach do you think?

Comment: Suppose a linear polynomial $s \in \Gamma(\mathcal O(1))$ is given. Over which set $U \subset \mathbb P^n$ does $s$ generate $\mathcal O(1)$, and where does it fail to do so? Then what happens if you add more sections?

Comment: Thanks this comment was very helpful! I get $s$ generates $\mathcal{O}(1)_P$ if and only if $s\notin P$ and more generally $s_1,...,s_m$ generate $\mathcal{O}(1)_P$ if and only if $s_i\notin P$ for some $I$. Then it is clear that if $m<n+1$ there is some homogeneous prime other than the irrelevant which contains all the $s_i'$s.